# On button click create dynamic form, autofill the data and post on url in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, url, post, payment-gateway, form-data

I am using AngularJS, I am trying to implement payment gateway in my web application and stuck at some step

So, at first step I have **JSON data** , Request method and Url on which I need to post the data.

**JSON data sample :**
{
   "key1" : value1,
   "key" : value2
}

**Request Method** : POST

**url** : myPaymentGatewayUrl

**My requirement is** :
When I click on button **Make Payment**, it should create a dynamic form and auto fill the data which I have in my JSON and and post that form data on **url**. This process should happen under the hood and I should redirect to payment gateway page.

**JS function**

```js
proceedToPayemnt: function(lead_id){

    var Payment = this;
    var payment_provider = this.payment_provider;
    var selected_payment_provider = this.selected_payment_provider;
    var user_profile = UserProfile.user_profile;

    var answer = selected_payment_provider[payment_provider.psp_id];
    
    if(answer == 1){
        var lead_id = 145282;
        Payment.offlinePayment(lead_id);
    }else{
         var lead_id = 145282;
        Payment.onlinePayment(lead_id);
    }                                                                                                                                                                                
   },
```

**The button code:**

```html
<button class="button" ng-click="proceedToPayemnt()">Make Payment</button>
```

Please suggest a solution for above problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-repeat to create controls from your JSON sample data, something like this will do that. If you dont want to display the form you can use ng-hide to hide the form, and onclick of the proceedToPayment button you can fire submitBtn click. I hope that should solve this.

```
<form action="URLHERE"  method="POST">
  <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in sampleData">
    <input type="text" id="{{key}}"  ng-model="sampleData[key]" />
    </div>
  <button id="submitBtn" type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution. I referred this [Programmatically submitting Angularjs form to an external url](http://shincoding.com/angularjs/programmatically-submitting-angularjs-form-to-an-external-url/?replytocom=234#respond)
and it worked.